# Make all possible combos in a string of numbers with split in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, permutation

I have an string of numbers "123456" i want to split them in all possible ways.

So

```
1 23456
1 2 3456
1 23 45 6
1234 5 6
and so on
```

What i have tried...

looping over len-1, and splitting on every index, but logically it misses a lot of possible scenarios.

Comment: is there something not obvious??

Comment: I want to split string in all possible ways it can be split

Comment: maximum split is `string.length-1`

Comment: It's not obvious why you posted it here. You want to split it. Good for you.

Comment: No, it's not. You haven't asked a question. It looks like a diary yet.

Comment: How to Make all possible combos with split ?

Comment: Put it in the question so that it was a question.

Comment: As of such short strings - try to imagine the spaces between characters are represented by a binary number, with `1` - there is a space and `0` there is no space. Now loop from `b00000` to `b11111`. Ex: `1 23 45 6` is a `10101`

Comment: i am lost a bit, can you show more examples

Comment: `1 2 3456` is `11000` because there is a space between 1st and 2nd chars, a space between 2nd and 3rd, but no between 3-4, 4-5 and 5-6. `1 23456` is `10000`, `1234 5 6` is `00011`

Comment: wow great, thanks, i am starting to see the correlation

Comment: Another way to look at it, all the ways to have 1 split + all the ways to have two splits + all the ways to have 3 splits... + all the ways to have len-1 splits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a recursive function like below...

```
<script lang="javascript">

  // Split string into all combinations possible
  function splitAllWays(result, left, right){
    // Push current left + right to the result list
    result.push(left.concat(right));
    //document.write(left.concat(right) + '<br />');

    // If we still have chars to work with in the right side then keep splitting
    if (right.length > 1){
      // For each combination left/right split call splitAllWays()
      for(var i = 1; i < right.length; i++){
        splitAllWays(result, left.concat(right.substring(0, i)), right.substring(i));
      }
    }

    // Return result
    return result;
  };

  var str = "123456";
  var ans = splitAllWays([], [], str);

</script>
```

**Results**

```
123456
1,23456
1,2,3456
1,2,3,456
1,2,3,4,56
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,45,6
1,2,34,56
1,2,34,5,6
1,2,345,6
1,23,456
1,23,4,56
1,23,4,5,6
1,23,45,6
1,234,56
1,234,5,6
1,2345,6
12,3456
12,3,456
12,3,4,56
12,3,4,5,6
12,3,45,6
12,34,56
12,34,5,6
12,345,6
123,456
123,4,56
123,4,5,6
123,45,6
1234,56
1234,5,6
12345,6
```

I think that is the right results (32 combinations).  Can someone confirm?

Comment: thanks i was wondering if it was possible at all without resorting to binary number

Comment: That's a great answer. I'd like to add a small modification in case the input needs to be an array. In such case, the function's first row would be: `result.push(left.concat(right.join('')));`, and the row inside the loop would be: `splitAllWays(result, left.concat(right.slice(0, i).join('')), right.slice(i, right.length));`

Comment: @OfirD i got error `right.join is not a function`

Comment: @LingLoeng as mentioned in my comment: *in case the input needs to be an array*. Meaning, `left` and `right` should be an array. According to your error, your `right` is not an array.