# All possible group variations of a string

Tags: javascript, combinations, permutation

Given a string `"abcdef"`

I would like to get an array of all possible combinations/permutations/variations as so:

```
['abcdef'],
['a', 'bcdef'],
['ab', 'cdef'],
['abc', 'def'],
['abcd', 'ef'],
['abcde', 'f'],
['a', 'b', 'cdef'],
['a', 'bc', 'def'],
['a', 'bcd', 'ef'],
['a', 'bcde', 'f'],
['ab', 'c', 'def'],
['ab', 'cd', 'ef'],
['ab', 'cde', 'f'],
['abc', 'd', 'ef'],
['abc', 'de', 'f'],
['abcd', 'e', 'f'],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'def'],
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'ef'],
['a', 'b', 'cde', 'f'],
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'ef'],
['a', 'bc', 'de', 'f'],
['a', 'bcd', 'e', 'f'],
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'ef'],
['ab', 'c', 'de', 'f'],
['ab', 'cd', 'e', 'f'],
['abc', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ef'],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'de', 'f'],
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e', 'f'],
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

What is the proper name for this task? This is not a combination and neither a permutation.

Each entry in the array should contain all letters in the input.

It would be great to have an example in JS.

Comment: `javascript split a string in all possible combinations` seems to yield results

Comment: thank you @Pekka웃 I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468474/make-all-possible-combos-in-a-string-of-numbers-with-split-in-javascript is the solution I was looking for.