# How to store all possible word derivations in a database efficiently?

Tags: database, data-structures

I have this code which takes short words (4 letter words in this case) and breaks them into two (or optionally 3) pieces, and then generates words from those parts.

```js
const words = load()
const derivations = words.map(w => analyze(words, w))
console.log(derivations
  .filter(({ list }) => list.length)
  .map(({ word, list }) => `${word} => ${list.map(x => `\n  ${x.join(':')}`).join('')}`).join('\n')
)

function analyze(words, word, listSize = 2) {
  const derivations = []

  const permutations = permute([], [], word)

  permutations.forEach(list => {
    if (list.length !== listSize) return
    resolve(words, list[0], list.slice(1)).forEach(derivation => {
      if (derivation.length) {
        derivations.push(derivation)
      }
    })
  })

  return { word, list: derivations }
}

function resolve(words, chunk, remainingList, isFirst = true, result = []) {
  words.forEach(word => {
    if (!word.match(/^[aeiou]/) && word.length === 4 && (word.startsWith(chunk)) && word !== chunk && word !== [chunk].concat(remainingList).join('')) {
      if (remainingList.length) {
        resolve(words, remainingList[0], remainingList.slice(1), false).forEach(array => {
          if (word !== array[0]) {
            result.push([word].concat(array))
          }
        })
      } else {
        result.push([ word ])
      }
    }
  })
  return result
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468474/make-all-possible-combos-in-a-string-of-numbers-with-split-in-javascript
function permute(result, left, right) {
  result.push(left.concat(right));

  if (right.length > 1) {
    for(var i = 1; i < right.length; i++) {
      permute(result, left.concat(right.substring(0, i)), right.substring(i));
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function load() {
  return `arch
back
bait
bake
ball
band
bank
bark
base
bash
bead
bear
beat
bell
belt
bend
best
bike
bill
bind
bird
bite
blob
blot
blow
blue
blur
boat
bolt
bond
book
boom
boot
boss
bowl
brew
brim
buck
buff
bulb
bulk
bull
bunk
burn
bush
bust
buzz
cake
call
calm
cane
card
care
cart
case
cash
cast
cave
char
chat
chew
chow
cite
clam
claw
clue
coal
coat
code
coin
comb
cone
cook
cool
cord
cork
cost
crab
crew
crib
crow
cube
cuff
cull
cure
curl
dare
dart
dash
date
daub
dawn
daze
deck
deed
dent
dice
diff
dish
disk
dive
dock
dole
doll
doom
dose
down
draw
drum
duck
duct
dude
duel
duke
dunk
dusk
dust
ease
etch
face
fade
fake
fare
farm
fast
fate
fawn
fear
feed
feel
file
fill
film
find
fine
fish
fizz
flat
flaw
flex
flow
flux
foam
fold
fool
fork
form
foul
free
fret
fuel
fume
fuse
fuss
fuzz
hack
haft
halt
hand
hare
harm
hash
haul
have
hawk
haze
head
heat
herd
hide
hike
hill
hint
hiss
hive
hold
hole
home
honk
hood
hoof
hook
hoot
horn
hose
host
howl
huff
hunt
hurt
hush
inch
keel
kern
kick
kill
kiln
kink
kiss
kite
knee
knit
knot
lace
lack
lake
land
lash
laze
lead
leaf
leak
lick
like
line
link
lint
list
load
loaf
loan
lock
look
loom
loot
lord
love
lull
lure
make
mark
mash
mask
mass
mate
maze
mean
meet
melt
mesh
mess
milk
mill
mime
mind
mine
mint
miss
mist
moan
mock
mold
molt
moon
moss
move
muse
mush
must
name
need
nerd
nest
nick
nose
note
null
oink
ooze
race
rack
raft
rake
rank
rant
rate
rave
read
reek
reel
rent
rest
ride
riff
rift
rise
risk
roar
robe
rock
role
roll
room
rose
rule
rush
rust
sack
salt
save
scam
scan
scar
seam
seat
seed
seek
self
sell
shed
shim
shoe
show
side
sift
silt
sink
site
size
skew
skid
skim
skin
slab
slam
sled
slot
snow
soak
sole
soot
sort
star
stem
stew
stir
stub
suck
suit
surf
swan
swim
take
talk
task
team
tear
tell
term
test
text
thaw
thud
tick
tide
tilt
time
toke
toll
tone
tool
toot
toss
tote
tour
tree
trek
trim
trot
tube
tuck
tune
turn
twin
vibe
view
void
vote
waft
wait
wake
walk
wall
want
wash
wave
wear
weed
weld
well
will
wind
wink
wish
wolf
word
work
worm
zone
zoom`.split(/\n+/)
}
```

Its output as you can see is like this for debugging purposes:

```
bake => 
  back:keel
  back:kern
  bait:keel
  bait:kern
  ball:keel
  ball:kern
  band:keel
  band:kern
  bank:keel
  bank:kern
  bark:keel
  bark:kern
  base:keel
  base:kern
  bash:keel
  bash:kern
band => 
  bank:dare
  bank:dart
  bank:dash
  bank:date
  bank:daub
  bank:dawn
  bank:daze
  bank:deck
  bank:deed
```

You'll notice that sometimes over 20 words on the left appear (nested, like `bank` 20+ times). There are only 400 some words, but the combinations number over 8000. If I have a list of 10,000 words, and longer words, and variable number of breakdowns instead of just 2 parts, it grows to enormous proportions.

What if I wanted to store every one of those derivations in a relational database? First, would a relational database be effective in this scenario? Two, what is a standard data structure which could efficiently represent this, in terms of size (sometimes my solution runs out of memory), and disk storage size if it were a DB. I can break these conceptually into models, such as the "Word" model and the "WordDerivation" model, etc.. But if they were each tables, there would be potentially tens of millions of rows just for this. How does a robust company implement such a thing like perhaps Google?

Currently I am trying to work on the data model side of an app side project. I want to show a word, and have it list the derivations for the word. A naive solution would be to search a 100,000 word list for potential matches on every request, but that is basically what I am precomputing here and it takes some time. So I am wondering how you might break it down for a database.

I am used to Rails model, but they seem quite heavy in this scenario, I am not sure. I would need Gigabytes to store this it seems like.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? Why are you "breaking the word up"? It is actually that you want to find words made from the letters of a given word, or is it truely that you want this particular algorithm?

Comment: I want this particular algorithm for breaking the words up and finding words made from the letters, correct. The data structure can change though, definitely. The algorithm can become more efficient too perhaps, though I don't see how to yet. But I am not asking about how to make a better algorithm necessarily, just how to efficiently store this for fetching.

Comment: You said yes to mutually exclusive options: is it A) you want to find words made from the letters of a given word (regardless of how that is done - ie not necessarily  "breaking up the word") or B) you must break up the word, *then* find other words that are made from those parts (which may be harder/slower and may produce different results from option A)?

Comment: I guess I don't necessarily need to partition the words first, I couldn't find another way to do it. So A sounds pretty good. But then for B, I want to find words that fit the patterns I have sort of started to vaguely define (only split the word into 2 or 3 parts, word must start with the chunk being tested, etc.). If you can do that without breaking up the word, that would be great, I just don't see how it's possible.

Comment: Sorry if I am still not clearly answering. I think I want a little of both. I am not sure if you _must_ break up the word, but still I want to find words that are made from the parts. But if you can explain an alternative approach you have in mind for A, I am all ears. Just don't know what you are imagining.

Comment: For some more context, I was trying to imagine like a Trie, where each _level_ in the word derivation list would get its own trie (that is, each "tree" node in the word list/tree would get its own trie). The words would be stored in that trie broken down by letter. So a 3-word derivation would have 3 levels of tries. But then I am like how on earth would you store that efficiently in a relational database. I would think I have to start _making my own database_ at that point, which is why I am asking how you would typically solve this.

Comment: Trie is the goto structure for storing and retrieving words very efficiently. Importantly, it's trivial to fit the entire English dictionary in memory. IMHO a relational database is not the best choice for the task of finding words using your criteria. Use a db to store words (maybe), but your service should probably load the dictionary into memory and work from there. If using a trie, you'd still be left with O(n2) retrievals, eg consider finding `eerie` from `rifle`. Think about finding the intersection of words indexed against every letter they contain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244449/discussion-between-lance-and-bohemian).

Comment: Why do you need to store these values? 
What are you intending to do with them?

Do you want to match them with some value to see if they obey the pattern? Do you want to use them to create combinations of values?

How you use this is of paramount importance in deciding what approach to take. 

You can certainly store this in SQL, but the real question is why? for what purpose?